# AWS Boto S3 API read KMS encrypted keys

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I tried to read keys which are encrypted by using AWS KMS, I first hit the following error.

> S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
>   
>   `InvalidArgument`Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.Authorizationnull1D584F77747CBB01LQIxPHmUGGDMnnI45xqWHtrB1+96tc7pDIEi6bVEE5i425SRypqeBXzvsH0CqPzwJe4xVv1UjhQ=

After setting `os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'`, the above 400 error is gone, but now I hit the 403 error.

> S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

May I ask if anyone hit the same issue before?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by a wrong S3 hostname which was `s3-ap-southeast-1.s3.amazonaws.com` but should be `s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`